# Bellman-Ford algorithm from Éva Tardos

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I am trying to understand the Bellman-Ford algorithm from Jon Kleinberg, Éva Tardos: *[Algorithm Design].
Page no: 296 The recursive equation that is written:
$$M[v]= \min(M[v], \min_{w\in V}
(c_{vw} + M[w]).$$

I am not getting how this equation is correct?
Because in the book it is written that $M[v]$ is the shortest path from $v-t$,
but shouldn't $M[v]$ be the shortest path from $s-v$ using at most $i-1$ edges?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. When something in a book seems off, restart reading at the start of the paragraph, sub-chapter or chapter. In ***6.8 Shortest Paths in a Graph***, there's a note starting *Let’s use OPT(i, v) to denote the minimum…* following the first proof. Also, look at the "dynamic programming table in (b)" two pages before the formula.

Comment: (While you're at it: I seem to have missed a closing parenthesis, and there is one "italics star" left from removing the URL.)

Comment: Yeah, because you told something about copyright, and I didn't knew If I had right to add link or not. So I removed the link